# What causes this missing whitespace after the macro name error?

Tags: c, microchip, mplab, xc16

I am working on a project in MPLAB X v3.35 for a PIC24F. At some point in the last few weeks the compiler has started giving the following warnings for every line in the compilation. What in the compiler line could be causing this? The column number doesn't seem to point to anything that makes sense and the only thing on there that isn't generated  by MPLAB is the `-DGIT_VERSION="v1.0-1-g14e8d84-d` flag which I've used a similar version to in a number of other projects.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc16\v1.26\bin\xc16-gcc.exe"   mcc_generated_files/oc4.c  -o build/PICkit3-XP/production/mcc_generated_files/oc4.o  -c -mcpu=24FJ64GA002  -MMD -MF "build/PICkit3-XP/production/mcc_generated_files/oc4.o.d"        -g -omf=elf -DGIT_VERSION="v1.0-1-g14e8d84-d" -DXPRJ_PICkit3-XP=PICkit3-XP  -legacy-libc    -I"mcc_generated_files" -I"../inc" -I"../dn-rdm-slave.X" -O0 -msmart-io=1 -Wall -msfr-warn=off  
<command-line>:0:13: warning: missing whitespace after the macro name
```

Comment: `XPRJ_PICkit3-XP` is not a valid macro name.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg If you downvoted him, would you please remove that.  I think in this case it's a valid question since the #define comes from the IDE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the latest version of MPLAB-X, microchip introduced a feature where it would define the configuration name in the build.  This would allow the user to make use of the configuration name for #ifs and the like (e.g. you want the display to show different text based on the config).  While most of the illegal characters were scrubbed, it looks like "-" was missed.

If you change the configuration name to use an underscore instead, that should eliminate these warnings.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I managed to work it out after JoachimPileborgs comment but this makes it much more obvious.